# MYSQL nested query running very slow?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, subquery

The following query is constantly timing out, is there a less overhead way to achieve the same function ?

```
UPDATE Invoices SET ispaid = 0 
WHERE Invoice_number IN (SELECT invoice_number
    FROM payment_allocation
    WHERE transactionID=305)
```

What I'm doing is unallocating invoices from a transaction, there can be up to 30+ records returned but it stops the database dead everytime I try to run it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

USE **JOIN** instead of **subquery** it will improve the performance.

Create index on **Invoice_number** column in both table if you haven't created.

Try this:

```
UPDATE Invoices i 
INNER JOIN payment_allocation pa ON i.Invoice_number = pa.invoice_number 
SET i.ispaid = 0 
WHERE pa.transactionID = 305;
```

Comment: Worked a TREAT ! 

So join tables with an inner instead of nesting for overhead :) awsome thnaks

Comment: @stevenmoffat Don't forgot to accept any of  the answer from all answers whichever you find works for yoy

Answer (score 2):

I'd try `EXISTS` :

```
UPDATE Invoices a set ispaid=0 
WHERE EXISTS 
(
 SELECT NULL FROM payment_allocation b 
 WHERE b.Invoice_number =a.Invoice_number AND b.transactionID=305
)
```

Comment: Why would you try exists ?

Comment: It seems logical and clear to me - you update the record in one table if there is at least on record that satisfies certain condition in another. `INNER JOIN` produces the same execution plan, and gives the same results, so no difference from performance point of view

Answer (score 1):

As of MySQL 5.5, Subquery Selects  (another full select statement inside the query) cannot be optimized.  This is probably why your query is so slow.  Refactor you query to get rid of the inner select statement.

```
 UPDATE Invoices, payment_allocation
  SET ispaid=0 
  WHERE payment_allocation.transactionID=305 AND       
        Invoices.Invoice_number = payment_allocation.invoice_number
```

An interesting sidenote... But MariaDB (a branch of MySQL by the original creator) has implemented Subquery select optimization.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE invoices i
  JOIN payment_allocation pa
    ON pa.invoice_number = i.invoice_number
   SET i.ispaid=0 
 WHERE pa.transactionID = 305;
```